# Why is there an delay when calling AlarmManager with an Pending Intent in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-intent, timer, android-pendingintent, countdowntimer

I literally searched everywhere I could and but just could not find a solution to this thing!!

So I am building an count down Timer app. But the problem I face is that each time it counts till 00:00.0, it waits an additional ~5seconds before it proceeds to sound the alarm. And if I happen to click anything in that period it crashes the app, but if I wait till it sounds the alarm and repeat the process it will wait ~5sec again but this time if I press Reset(during or after those 5sec) for example, it is working just fine! Here is the error:

```html
07-13 14:51:08.838 8808-8808/tech.dronerace.productivitytimer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-13 14:51:08.838 8808-8808/tech.dronerace.productivitytimer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: tech.dronerace.productivitytimer, PID: 8808
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service tech.dronerace.productivitytimer.Ringtone@11d1fec with Intent { cmp=tech.dronerace.productivitytimer/.Ringtone (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.stop()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3027)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1442)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.stop()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at tech.dronerace.productivitytimer.Ringtone.onStartCommand(Ringtone.java:52)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3010)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1442) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
07-13 14:56:09.149 8808-8808/tech.dronerace.productivitytimer I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8808 SIG: 9
```

and here is my method code:

```
public void countDone() {
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b_start)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b_reset)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b_stop)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer_id)).setText("00:00");
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerMs_id)).setText(".0");

    //----------------Alarm && Vibration && Progress----------------\\

    final Intent i = new Intent(SecondStep.this, Alarm.class);
    i.putExtra("extra", "soundOn");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pi);
    } else {
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pi);
    }


    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_reset);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            updateTimer(startTimeInitialG);
            i.putExtra("extra", "soundOff");
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            sendBroadcast(i);

            clickReset(v);

            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b_start)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b_reset)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

Now I chose the Pending Intent as this way I can put Extras to determine weather the music has been shut down by pressing the reset button or is it still playing. So knowingly that it is an Pending intent I set it up to fire immediately as well as for the Alarm to be exact(see the code above)as well as the flag to Update. But nothing seems to help. I then also switched from my custom built timer to CountDownTimer class thinking that there might be an inherit fault in AlarmManager being used for Timer but the same problem reappeared.

Why is my alarm being called with an delay? What am I doing wrong? :P

PS here is my Ringtone class(due to the error).

```
public class Ringtone extends Service {

MediaPlayer alarmPlayer;
boolean isRunning;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //get info on weather the reset was pressed and convert it to int so you can see weather you play or stop the music
    String state = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");
    assert state != null; //prevents app from crashing
    switch (state) {
        case "soundOn":
            startId = 1;
            break;
        case "soundOff":
            startId = 0;
            break;
        default:
            startId = 0;
            break;
    }



    Log.e("Is the state = 1 or 0?", state);
    System.out.println(startId);

    //we pressed reset or ('soundOff' ->extra) then cut it off
    if(startId == 0 ) {

        alarmPlayer.stop();
        alarmPlayer.reset();
        isRunning = false;
    }
    //we pressed nothing and is automatically ('soundOn' ->extra) so let it play
    else if(startId == 1) {

        alarmPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.imperialmarch);
        alarmPlayer.start();
        isRunning = true;
    }




    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e("On Destroy called..", "yes");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Comment: Why dont use CountDownTimer instead of AlarmManager?

Comment: Tried that, the same problem.. :P I wrote it all in my question above
I think the problem is that Intent is not yet being created and when I click to reset I am trying to stop() something that is not made yet... dunno

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a `PendingIntent` and setting an alarm that should go off immediately to trigger your `BroadcastReciever`? You can just send the broadcast `Intent` yourself, like this:

```
final Intent i = new Intent(SecondStep.this, Alarm.class);
i.putExtra("extra", "soundOn");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

This will trigger immediately, and you don't need a `PendingIntent`, nor the involvement of the alarm manager.